# How to get all products ID, product category in array Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product

I want to get all products id in magento 2. I tried many times but it is not working. Thanks in Advance

Actually I'm using plugin to hide price and add to cart button now I want to hide the price and add to cart button for specific categories.. like you can see in image
[image]

now to hide add to cart and price for specific categories my code is

```
> namespace PME\Hideprice\Plugin

<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace PME\Hideprice\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use PME\Hideprice\Helper\Data as Helper;

/**
 * Class IsSalablePlugin
 *
 * @category Plugin
 * @package  PME\Hideprice\Plugin
 */
class IsSalablePlugin
{
    /**
     * Scope config
     *
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * HTTP Context
     * Customer session is not initialized yet
     *
     * @var Context
     */
    protected $context;

    protected $_initialValue = false;

    const DISABLE_ADD_TO_CART = 'pme_hideprice/general/catalog_frontend_disable_add_to_cart_for_guest';

    /**
     * SalablePlugin constructor.
     *
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig ScopeConfigInterface
     * @param Context              $context     Context
     */
    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        Context $context,
        Helper $helper
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->_helper = $helper;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public function afterIsSalable(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject,
        $result
    )
    {

        $categories_main=$this->_helper->arrayData();
        $categories = array_pop($categories_main);
        $categoriess[] = $categories;

        $allowed= $this->_helper->getCurrentCategory();
        $result=array_intersect($categoriess,$allowed);

        if (!empty($result)) {

        $this->initialValue = $result;
        $scope = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE; 
            if($this->_helper->getIsEnable()) {
                if ($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::DISABLE_ADD_TO_CART, $scope)) {
                    if ($this->_helper->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                } 
                return true; 
            }    
            return $result;   
        }
    }

    public function afterGetIsSalable (
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject,
        $result
    ) {

        $categories_main=$this->_helper->arrayData();
        $categories = array_pop($categories_main);
        $categoriess[] = $categories;

        $allowed= $this->_helper->getCurrentCategory();
        $result=array_intersect($categoriess,$allowed);

        if (!empty($result)) {

            $scope = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE; 
            if($this->_helper->getIsEnable()) {
                if ($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::DISABLE_ADD_TO_CART, $scope)) {
                    if ($this->_helper->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return $this->initialValue;
                }
                return true;  
            } 
            return $result;
         }
    }    
}
```

now for this my Helper is

> PME\Hideprice\Helper

```
<?php
namespace PME\Hideprice\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{

    protected $getarray;

    /**
     * Scope config
     *
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * HTTP Context
     * Customer session is not initialized yet
     *
     * @var Context
     */

    protected $context;

     /**
     * SalablePlugin constructor.
     *
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig ScopeConfigInterface
     * @param Context              $context     Context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
     */

    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $helpercontext,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $_customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {

        $this->_customerSession = $_customerSession;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($helpercontext);
    }

    public function isCustomerLoggedIn() {

        return $this->context->getValue(CustomerContext::CONTEXT_AUTH);
        //to check login mean that to check that the customer is logged in or not
    }

    public function getIsEnable(){
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('pme_hideprice/general/enabled', 
                                            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }

    public function isEnabled($scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            'pme_hideprice/general/enabled',
            $scope
        );
    }

    public function arrayData(){

            $getarray = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('pme_hideprice/general/category',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
            return explode ( ',',$getarray);

    }

    /**
 * Return catalog current category object
 *
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
 */

public function getCurrentCategory()
{
    return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
}



}
```

now in this the issue is I'm using registry and the registry only get the current product category.. so its not works properly.
[image]

maybe after this problem might be logic problem if you can also set it for me I'll be really thankful to you

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @VivekKumar ok buddy I'm going to upload the code... n the purpose for what I want to use it... it will be really glad for me if you solve my problem coz this is now gonna headache for me.

Comment: @VivekKumar buddy I just upload the code I wish that you will solve my Problem Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ProductRepository` to get all Products Id in `Magento 2`.

Maybe this code will useful for you:

```
class Product extends Action
{
    private $productRepository;
    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        $criteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        $products = $this->productRepository->getList($criteria);
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $this->getResponse()->appendBody(sprintf(
                    "(%d)",
                    $product->getId())
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: This is overkill as it loads full product models when you only need IDs...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

```
$allowed= $this->_helper->getCurrentCategory();
$result=array_intersect($categoriess,$allowed);
```

`$allowed` is not an array. It's an instance of the category model.
you can change to this:

```
$result=array_intersect($categoriess, [$allowed->getId()]);
```

Comment: now it gives me the further problem
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\PME\Hideprice\Plugin\IsSalablePlugin.php:71 Stack trace